# sed replace backslash double quote with single quote

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to take the following:

```
echo "'{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'"
```

And end up with the following via using SED:

```
{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

Comment: you should just use sed /s/... for substitute and work your way through that. Your question sounds like going to a code/script vending machine..

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash's string replace:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a='{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'

# Replaces all occurrences of \" with '
b=${a//\\\"/\'}

# Debug prints converted string
printf '%s\n' "$b"
```

Comment: hey dude! ve updated the question, i think i was unclear

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'| tr -d '\\'|tr '"' "'"
echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'| sed "s/.\"/'/g"
echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'| awk '{gsub(/\\"/, "\047"); print}'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

#### update (new string)

```
echo "'{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'"| tr -d "'"|tr '"' "'"
echo "'{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'"| sed "s/'//g; s/\"/'/g"
echo "'{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}'"| awk '{gsub(/\047/, ""); gsub(/"/, "\047"); print}'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

Comment: hey dude! ve updated the question, i think i was unclear

Comment: @basickarl: answer updated with the new string!

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE 1 : if you insist on `sed`, then it's :

```
   echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' |
   
    sed -E 's/\\["]/\x27/g'   
                            # BSD-sed

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}

   echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' |
   
   gsed -E 's/\\["]/\x27/g'   
                            # GNU-sed
{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

===============================

UPDATE 2 : if you're not comfortable dealing with octal codes in `awk`, then it's

```
gawk -e 'NF++~—-NF' FS='\\\\"' OFS="'" 

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

===============================

A relatively portable `awk`-based solution

```
echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' | 
gawk      NF=NF FS='\\\\\42' OFS='\47'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}

echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' | 
gawk -Pe  NF=NF FS='\\\\\42' OFS='\47'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}

echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' | 
gawk -ce  NF=NF FS='\\\\\42' OFS='\47'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}

echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' |
mawk      NF=NF FS='\\\\\42' OFS='\47'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}

echo '{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\", \"kind\":\"two\"}' | 
mawk2     NF=NF FS='\\\\\42' OFS='\47'

{'apiVersion':'apps/v1', 'kind':'two'}
```

Comment: hey dude! ve updated the question, i think i was unclear